# Laravel 4 Relationship: a message belong to two user

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I am making user to user messaging system in laravel 4. So in a simplified version i have to table

First table

**Users**

user_id | 
user_name

Second table

**Messages**

message_id |
message_from_user_id |
message_to_user_id |
message_content |

So after reading the documentation I learned that User has many message and message belongs to User.

*But how do I actually relate them in coding?*

**I am quite confused how will I use the foreign key in this case for a message that will have two user?**

Comment: This maybe helpful: http://paste.laravel.com/8nI (from http://forums.laravel.io/viewtopic.php?id=3170)

Comment: @FDL Thanks for the link, its helpful to make me understand more about relationship but not yet answer my question :( ( how to relate a single message to two user )

Comment: Pivot tables are your friends

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check this out: http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#many-to-many

Basically you need a table structure like this

Users: id | username

Messages: id | from | content

user_messages: user_id | message_id

---

You can define your models like this

```
class User extends Eloquent {

    public function messages()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Message');
    }

    public function sent_messages()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Messages', 'from');
    }

}

class Message extends Eloquent {

    public function from()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('User', 'from');
    }

    public function to()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('User');
    }
}
```