# Laravel private messaging system . Fetch all related users issue

Tags: laravel, eloquent, private, messaging

I am referring to this thread 
[Laravel 4 Relationship: messaging system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25429229/laravel-4-relationship-messaging-system/38405777)

I created the tables and also made the relations inside both model "Message" and "User".
Now i can fetch the list of messages sent by me through this command
user::find($myid)->sent_messages()->get();

MY QUESTIONS IS

How can we get list of users that has been messaging to me (logged in user) ? 
I mean in the messages table "from" can be logged in user (1) or "to" can be logged in user (1) . I want to get list of other users that are chatting with the (logged in user) .

Hope you understand my question and help. I am new to laravel and trying to learn things and best practises. If you have suggestion to use any messaging system already there in github. I found one name "Laravel-messenger" but not suited to me.

Your suggestions and answer are highly appreciated. THANKS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be instead of using table user_messages (just drop it) you just modify table Messages to below form:

```
Messages: id | from_user_id | to_user_id | content
```

Then you can make query:

```
$received = Messges::where('to_user_id','=',my_user_id);
$send = Messges::where('from_user_id','=',my_user_id);
$result = $received->union($send)->get();
```

(BONUS: you can also add column `replay_from_message_id` (null for first message) to save backward sequence of messages (thread). And then you can also add column `first_message_id` to simplify getting thread query)

Comment: The query $result = Messges::where('to_user_id','=',my_user_id);
Will return messages collection where "to_user_id" = mine id right ?
It means those messages that someone sent to me right ? What if the first message wil be the one i sent to someone. WIll this same query work there too ? Thanks

Comment: if you wan messages that you send to someone then just use: $result = Messges::where('from_user_id','=',my_user_id); (you can also use eloquent `union` to'merge' this two types of query).

Comment: In above solution you will also not have any problems when some user delete message. Then you can add two boolean columns 'deleted_by_sender' and 'deleted_by_receiver' if each is true then you can delete row.

Comment: How about fetching like this from the users model

public function messages() {
 return $this->hasMany(Message::class, 'to');
}

public function sent_messages() {
 return $this->hasMany(Message::class, 'from');
}


and then in controller do something like this

$currentUser = Auth::user()->id;

$users1 = User::find($currentUser)->messages()->get();
$users2 = User::find($currentUser)->sent_messages()->get();

$AllUsers = $users1->merge($users2);

Comment: You can try in this way. I only show you idea - you can implement it by adding message() and sent_messages() to User model. If this informations help you, please click on gray 'check' on the left side of my answer (below points).

Comment: Yes Thanks for the idea . It clears my concept. THanks :)